# Output of foreach saves as a large file

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am struggling with getting a reasonable size of the output of `foreach` loop in R when saved as `.Rdata` file. Basically, I fit several mixed effect models using different data sets, store the model outputs in a list and then save the list as `.Rdata` file.

In an illustrative example of my problem you can see that the sizes of the output objects (here mod_list and mod_list2) are the same when employing either for loop (sequential computation) or foreach loop (parallelized computation).

#sequential

```
library(lme4)
mod_list <- vector("list", length = 5)

for (i in 1:5) {
  #fit each model using a unique dataset
  m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), sleepstudy[-i,])
  mod_list[i] <- list(m)
}
```

#parallel

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

UseCores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(UseCores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

mod_list2 <- foreach(i=1:5) %dopar% {
  library(lme4)
  #fit each model using a unique dataset
  m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), sleepstudy[-i,])
  m

}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Output object sizes:

```
print(object.size(mod_list), units = "auto")
```

> 143 Kb

```
print(object.size(mod_list2), units = "auto")
```

> 143 Kb

However, what differs is the size of the `.Rdata` files when saved (here 172 kB and 611 kB for mod_list and mod_list2, respectively).

Further, we can see that in for loop the models are fitted in the global R environment:

```
lapply(1:5, function (x) attributes(attributes(mod_list[[x]]@frame)$terms)$.Environment)
```

> [[1]] <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
>
> [[2]] <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
>
> [[3]] <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
>
> [[4]] <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
>
> [[5]] <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

while models coming from `foreach` loop are fitted each in a unique environment:

```
lapply(1:5, function (x) attributes(attributes(mod_list2[[x]]@frame)$terms)$.Environment)
```

> [[1]] <environment: 0x00000166d0383b20>
>
> [[2]] <environment: 0x00000166d07f54d0>
>
> [[3]] <environment: 0x00000166cff38db0>
>
> [[4]] <environment: 0x00000166d1df1bb0>
>
> [[5]] <environment: 0x00000166d206ecc8>

I suspect that this difference in environments between for and foreach loops is the reason of much larger `.Rdata` files in the latter case (in my real task they are six times larger). I have tried to use compression `xz` with various compression levels when saving the output but the reduction of the file size is not satisfactory.

**My question is**: Is there a way to reduce the output file size when using foreach loop?

Comment: Do you *need* the data in the environment? I’m assuming you don’t, in which case you can just remove it from the `m` object inside the `foreach` call. That should lead to a correspondingly reduced file size.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I suspect they might need it because it contains `i`. They should do the subsetting outside the call to `lmer`.

Comment: @Roland Does `lmer` perform non-standard evaluation of the `data` argument (besides determining the printable object name)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't know. I know that there are methods for `lm` objects that modify the call and evaluate it. I suspect something similar could be the case for `merMod` objects.

Comment: Have you used `ls` to check what these environments contain? I suspect they contain `i` and the data (maybe even the whole lme4 package namespace because that's where the data is defined?). Both might be needed later. But of course, you don't need to store the data 5 times.

Comment: @Konrad In my real task I store the models and data in separate lists. Then deleting the data from `m` makes sense. I tried to replace `m@frame` by an empty data.frame. However, even though the size of the list mod_list2 decreased to 73.8 kB, the .Rdata output is still large (600 kB).

Comment: @Roland In the real task we do the data subsetting before fitting a model, i.e. outside the `lmer` call. Now I see it was a bit inappropriate to include `i` into the formula. The idea in the example was to just consider different data sets in each model.

Comment: I tried to check the individual environments, but how to access them? In RStudio they are not listed in the Environment tab. It was possible to only see their attributes via `ls(attributes(attributes(mod_list2[[1]]@frame)$terms)$.Environment)` (this is for the first model) showing it contains `i` and `m`.

Comment: I suggest you simply remove that environment and test if methods for `update` and other functions you might like to use (e.g., from the emmeans package) still work. I suspect you'll run into issues.